# cat and grep from multiple files in python and write output to a file?

Tags: python, sh

i want a python equivalent of shell command `cat logs/archived/app.2020-12-11* | grep "Sending" > sms_otp_logs_ack.log`

I have tried by using sh module.

```
sh.grep(sh.cat(2020-12-18/100.6.13.16/app.*), string_to_grep)
```

This throws an error of no such file due to * wild card. How can i pypass this and also save the output to another file?

Comment: Did you try the python module os? check os.system() and use the same shell command as argument to os.system()

Comment: The `cat` is mildly useless here; like basically every properly written file manipulation tool, `grep` accepts an arbitrary number of file name arguments, with the marked benefit that it can print which file it found a match in if you would like that.

Comment: can you provide me the edited shell command to grep from all those files @tr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module which finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern according to the rules used by the Unix shell, and then those found files are opened up in read mode to be searched for the desired string(`"Sending"`) in order the lines containing that string are to be appended to another file.

```
import glob, os

for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "app.2020-12-11*")):
    with open(f, 'r') as f_in, open('sms_otp_logs_ack.log', 'a') as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            if "Sending" in line:
                f_out.write(line)
```